# Socket exception while making Http calls

Tags: c#, .net, http, azure-functions

I have a blob triggered azure function (v2) hosted with `App Service plan(S3)`. The function process a json file and makes `Http calls` to APIs exposed in API management service.

I'm using `HttpClient` to make `Http` calls. Although this works fine in one environment with same set up, it is failing while making http post calls in another environment.

The exception :

> `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` with error message 
>   "The operation was canceled. Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"

Quick googling revealed me that it may happen because of excess http connections. More details here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#connections-limit

The solution was to use static `HttpClient` or scale out App service plan. I did both only to realise that it still fails with same exception.

Has any one encountered this issue?

Any insights would be helpful.

Edit: Here is the code that makes http call

```
public class ReportingService : IReportingService
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ReportingService(ILogger<ReportingService> logger, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["ReportingServiceBaseUrl"]);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{configuration["APIUser"]}:{configuration["APIPassword"]}")));
        }

        public async Task<bool> RequestReport(string endpoint, StringContent httpContent)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, httpContent);
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Migration failed");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be really great if you could post an [mcve] of your code that's throwing the issue

Comment: What lifetime scope does have *ReportingService* (singletone, etc)?

Comment: @vladimir yes it is singleton

Comment: So it works in one environment and fails in the other. Then the problem doesn't have to be in your code. Look at the differences in environments. Does the non-working environment have a firewall, for example?

Comment: Could you provide the following information so we can investigate from the product group side?

- Function App version (1.0 or 2.0)
- Function App name
- Function name(s) (as appropriate)
- Region
If you don't want to give your function app name, you can do so privately by https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: You can use *Development tools -> Advanced tool (Kudu)* to check availability your endpoint (use commands *tcpping*, *curl*). Maybe your endpoint is located in separated VNet and you need to set connection with this virtual network (see *Networking -> VNet*) ?

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT please see the details. Time - 2019-07-02T06:49:55.457, execution id - 7cc8f7f3-a2f5-4266-abaf-66a41c10d740, Region - Australia East

Comment: @CodeCaster  The AppService plan, region are same for both the environments. I'm also able to trigger the API independently from Postman

Comment: @PNDev could you please comment on how you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

From the back-end logs there is only execution and unfortunately that is failed one.

**Exception Details**

Timestamp : 7/2/2019 6:49:55 AM 
Inner Exception Type: System.FormatException

```html
Full Exception :
 System.FormatException : Invalid blob path specified : ''. Blob identifiers must be in the format 'container/blob'.
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.BlobPath.ParseAndValidate(String value,Boolean isContainerBinding) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Blobs\BlobPath.cs : 53
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Triggers.StringToCloudBlobConverter.ConvertAsync(String input,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Blobs\Triggers\StringToCloudBlobConverter.cs : 21
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.BlobOutputConverter`1.TryConvertAsync[TInput](Object input,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Blobs\BlobOutputConverter.cs : 35
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Converters.CompositeAsyncObjectToTypeConverter`1.TryConvertAsync[T](Object value,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Converters\CompositeAsyncObjectToTypeConverter.cs : 28
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Triggers.BlobTriggerBinding.BindAsync(Object value,ValueBindingContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Blobs\Triggers\BlobTriggerBinding.cs : 158
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer.TriggerWrapper.BindAsync(Object value,ValueBindingContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Indexers\FunctionIndexer.cs : 475
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.TriggeredFunctionBinding`1.BindCoreAsync[TTriggerValue](ValueBindingContext context,Object value,IDictionary`2 parameters) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Triggers\TriggeredFunctionBinding.cs : 57
```

Please let me know if there is any date and time in UTC in which you observe

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Comment: Hi Can you please check this execution? Time - 2019-07-03 00:37:01.993, Operation Id - 59fcaa7cdbc97b4e817129222f9c2932, Region - Australia East

Comment: Hi PNDEV,   FunctionInvocationId seems to be incorrect. Can you check again and provide the correct one.

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT  could you please elaborate on what was the issue here and how it got fixed? i am facing the similar issue and couldnt find any other explanation other than this thread